# MySQL - Group By multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, group-by

Im trying to group cerain info together but the way type A and type B data looks is very different.

what im trying to figure out is how to create a condition inside a group by statement.

ie

---

GROUP BY

```
click.employee_id, click.mode, asset.location, click.paper_size, asset.name
```

OR

```
click.mode, asset.location, click.paper_size, asset.name
```

HAVING click.employee_id >= 10000000

---

If the employee_id is greater than 100000 it should only group by the 2nd condition, and not with the click.employee_id in mind.

Thanx in advance

Comment: To help visualize what you're trying to achieve, what are you trying to SELECT out of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a CASE statement in the GROUP BY

Something like

```
GROUP BY

CASE WHEN click.employee_id > 100000 THEN 1 ELSE click.employee_id END , 
click.mode, 
asset.location, 
click.paper_size, 
asset.name
```

Comment: brilliant, your previous post actually was the one i used.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @astander.  However, one caveat...

Before SQL actually starts processing a query, it actually runs it two times. Once just to get a final output structure of the query to know the final column widths and data types.  If the first record encounted by the engine is an employee ID LESS THAN the 100,000 range, the CASE will return a 1 and might use a smaller data column type than the employee ID column.  So, to fix, you might want to do

then 00000001 else click.employee_id ...

At least I've seen this happen before and just a heads-up on it.